# Using ereg_replace in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

How do I replace using the following code?

```
ereg_replace("%Data_Index\[.\]%", $this->resultGData[$key ][\\1], $var)
```

I want to replace the number in [] `%Data_Index`
to `$this->resultGData[$key ][\\1]` same `%Data_Index`
and how `ex %Data_Index[1] = $this->resultGData[$key][1], $var);`

replace number in `%Data_Index[...........]` in `[]`
to `$this->resultGData[$key ][............]`
same number

Comment: please try again. This is simply *impossible* to decipher.

Comment: He has a string where he wants %Data_Index[X] to be replaced with $this->resultGData[$key][X]

Comment: i am thai ,english not common lang sorry for that

Comment: You could at least try to use the proper markdown to format your question -- that is, if you want people's help. It generally helps others to decipher questions.

Comment: Could someone edit his question to properly display code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [`preg_replace()` function](http://docs.php.net/preg_replace) with the [`e` modifier](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) instead:

```
preg_replace('/%Data_Index\[(\d+)\]%/e', '$this->resultGData[$key][\1]', $var);
```

Note that this function uses [Perl-compatible regular expressions](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php) instead of POSIX-extended regular expression.

Answer (score -2):

your question is a little bit hard to understand

the smartest way to replace what you are asking I believe would be using a cycle

for example if you know that $this->resultGData[$key ][] has 10 elements on them you could simply do this, asuming %Data_Index[1] (are you sure it isn't $Data_Index? i'll asume that) you can try the following

```
$total = count($this->resultGData[$key ]);  //we get the total of elements in that key

for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++)
{
  $Data_Index[$i] = $this->resultGData[$key][$i];
}
```

now if the $key changes, you'd need to do this for every $key :)

keep practicing your english, it's a really useful tool in the IT field :) (not that i'm very a good at it either :P)